# Copying specific columns from multiple sheets after active sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to code a VBA that selects the first column of every sheet after the active sheet I am on (this will change), and copies into the newly created sheet which will appear after the active sheet

This code below won't work but hopefully it gives an idea of what I am trying to achieve

```
Dim sht As ActiveSheet

Sheets(after.sht).Columns("1").copy 'I want to copy column one from every sheet after the current sheet I'm on
Sheets.Add after:=sht.paste 'then paste into a new sheet which appears after the Active sheet I started on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyColumns()

Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Destination As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Checking whether "Master" sheet already exists in the workbook
For Each Source In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Source.Name = "Master" Then
        MsgBox "Master sheet already exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

'Inserting new worksheets in the workbook
Set Destination = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("Main"))

'Renaming the worksheet
Destination.Name = "Master"

'Looping through the worksheets in the workbook
For Each Source In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets


    If Source.Name <> "Master" And Source.Name <> "Main" Then

        'Finding the last column from the destination sheet
        Last = Destination.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

        If Last = 1 Then
            'Pasting the data in the destination sheet
            Source.UsedRange.Copy Destination.Columns(Last)
        Else
            Source.UsedRange.Copy Destination.Columns(Last + 1)
        End If
    End If
Next

Columns.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Dim flagSh    As Worksheet
Dim newSh     As Worksheet
Dim i         As Long

With ThisWorkbook
  If ActiveSheet.Index = .Worksheets.Count Then Exit Sub
  Set flagSh = ActiveSheet
  .Worksheets.Add , flagSh
  Set newSh = ActiveSheet

  For i = .Worksheets.Count To newSh.Index + 1 Step -1
    .Worksheets(i).Columns(1).Copy
    newSh.Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
  Next
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Hope this helps you get started.